# CSS animation for moving div to top and then to center

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to make a CSS animation (i can't use javascript) with these steps:

1. Have a div of which you can't know in advance its position or size (in the fiddle i have set the size for testing)
2. The div gets resized (width 100% height 50 pixels) and moves to the top of the page while its content disappears
3. The div turns into a circle and moves to the center of the page

This is what i have attempted so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/v3bt1mar/5/

```
.turning {
  width: 80%;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
.turning:active {
  background: red;
  animation: 10.5s;
  display: block !important;
  position: fixed;

  content: "";
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: resizeList 10.5s forwards;
}
.turning:active * {
  animation: fadeContent 1s forwards;
}
@keyframes  fadeContent {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes  resizeList {

  25% {
    width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      top: 10px;
      left: 0%;
      // transform: translate(0%, 0%) rotateY(0deg);
      border-radius: 0%;
  }
  100% {
      border-radius: 50%;
      top: calc(50% - 50px);
      left: calc(50% - 50px)";
      // transform: translate(~"calc(50vw - 50px)", ~"calc(50vh - 50px)") rotateY(180deg);
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
  }
}
```

But it's still far from what i am expecting.
On Mozilla it doesn't move vertically, on Chrome it does move but not smoothly (just at every keyframe, apparently)
Then i don't know why it moves back to the left rather than to the center of the page
On top of that it works differently on Mozilla and Chrome (on Mozilla it doesn't move to the top, on Chrome it does but not smoothly)

Comment: to know what i am missing in my css in order to make it work the way i want

Comment: you want to remove lagginess??

Comment: I want it to do what i have described, which it doesn't at the moment

Comment: See my edited question, i have added at the end what it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual issue was that it was copied from a less file and it contained single line comments which are not allowed into normal CSS. On top of that i had left calc as a string so that LESS won't sum the values while parsing

With a few adjustments taken from the other answers i managed to fix the animation the way i wanted (the rotate was intended, i just didn't think it was worth mentioning)

https://jsfiddle.net/v3bt1mar/12/

```
.turning {
  width: 80%;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
.turning:active {
  background: red;
  display: block !important;
  position:fixed;

  overflow: hidden;
  animation: resizeList 1s forwards;
  top:calc(50% - 50px);
  left: 0;
}
.turning:active * {
  animation: fadeContent 1s forwards;
}
@keyframes  fadeContent {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes  resizeList {

  25% {
    width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      top: 10px;
      left: 0%;
      border-radius: 0%;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
      border-radius: 50%;
      top: calc(50% - 50px);
      left: calc(50% - 50px);
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
100% {
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  left: calc(50% - 50px)";
  // transform: translate(~"calc(50vw - 50px)", ~"calc(50vh - 50px)") rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
```

}

To:

```
100% {
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  left: 50%;
  // transform: translate(~"calc(50vw - 50px)", ~"calc(50vh - 50px)") rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
```

}

This will keep image at center. Also try adding keyframes for 50% and 75% transition. That should smooth out the transition a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you add `position:absolute;` to `.turning` and remove the rotate transformation in the keyframe, the animation does what you are describing: https://jsfiddle.net/v3bt1mar/7/